# Conditionally change the value of the current row, based on the value of Nth row below of a csv using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, csv

I am trying to conditionally change the value of a current row, based on the value of the Nth row below it. say for example I have a csv file that looks like:

```
   trial
    ''
    ''
    ''
    ''
    ''
    ''
    ''
    'a'
    ''
    ''
    ''
    ''
    ''
    ''
    ''
    'a'
    ''
    ''
    ''
    ''
    ''
    ''
    ''
    'a'
```

Now,if the value of every 3rd row after the current row is 'a', then the null will be converted into 'a' from the current row to the 3rd row below.
as such:

```
trial
''
''
''
''
'a'
'a'
'a'
'a'
''
''
''
''
'a'
'a'
'a'
'a'
''
''
''
''
'a'
'a'
'a'
'a'
```

my code is as follow:

```
data =csv.reader(data)
next(data)

def convert(param):
    if param=='':
        value='a'
    else:
        value=''
    return value

for row in data:
    i=0
    for line in islice(data, i+3, None):
        print i
        print line
        print row
        if line==['a']:
            convert(row)
        print row
        i = i+1
```

however, the output is:

```
0
[]
[]
[]
1
[]
[]
[]
2
[]
[]
[]
3
['a']
[]
[]
4
[]
[]
[]
5
[]
[]
[]
6
[]
[]
[]
7
[]
[]
[]
8
[]
[]
[]
9
[]
[]
[]
10
[]
[]
[]
11
[]
[]
[]
12
[]
[]
[]
13
['a']
[]
[]
14
[]
[]
[]
15
[]
[]
[]
16
[]
[]
[]
17
[]
[]
[]
18
[]
[]
[]
19
[]
[]
[]
20
[]
[]
[]
21
[]
[]
[]
22
[]
[]
[]
23
['a']
[]
[]
```

any idea on how to do this?

Comment: can you please make this more readable? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `fillna` with `backfill`

First, you need to make sure your empty values are actually null values recognized by pandas, so

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = df.replace('', np.NaN).fillna(method='bfill', limit=3).replace(np.NaN, '')

   trial
0       
1       
2       
3       
4      a
5      a
6      a
7      a
8       
9       
10      
11      
12     a
13     a
14     a
15     a
16      
17      
18      
19      
20     a
21     a
22     a
23     a
```

Comment: Get rid of the last replace if you don't mind having NaN values in your column, instead of `''`

Comment: Your solution is short and elegant! Thank you so much @ALollz

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over rows using `iterrows()` to achieve the result:

```
# if the values have quotes, you can remove the quotes first
df1['trial'] = df1['trial'].str.replace("'",'')

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['trial'] == 'a':
        df1.loc[index-3:index, 'trial'] = 'a'
    else:
        continue

# output

    trial
0   
1   
2   
3   
4   a
5   a
6   a
7   a
8   
9   
10  
11  
12  a
13  a
14  a
15  a
16  
17  
18  
19  
20  a
21  a
22  a
23  a
```